# How to change the entity to linq

Tags: c#, linq, model-view-controller

I want to change this code from entity to linq.

I always get the error "value cannot be null. parameter name: text"
how to fix that error

```
public ActionResult Search(SearchView search)
{
    IEnumerable<Transaction> thunhaps = null, chitieus = null;
    decimal totalTN = 0, totalCT = 0;
    int userid = Convert.ToInt32(Session["userid"]);
    //var trans = new List<Transaction>();
    QuanLyChiTieuDataContext context = new QuanLyChiTieuDataContext();
    List<Transaction> trans = new List<Transaction>();
    if (search.MoTa != null)
        search.MoTa = "";
    if (search.TransType == "i" || search.TransType == "b")
    {
        
        thunhaps = from item in context.ThuNhaps
                  where item.UserID == userid
                  && item.MoTa.Contains(search.MoTa)
                   && item.Ngay.Value >= search.TuNgay &&
                    item.Ngay <= search.DenNgay
                  select new Transaction
                  {
                      Id = item.Inc_Id,
                      SoTien = (decimal)item.SoTien,
                      MoTa = item.MoTa,
                      GhiChu = item.GhiChu,
                      NgayGD = item.Ngay.Value,
                      TransType = "Income"
                  };

        totalTN = thunhaps.Sum(t => t.SoTien);
        //List<ThuNhap> thuNhaps = new List<ThuNhap>();
        //var totalTNhap = thuNhaps.Sum(t => t.SoTien); 

    }

   
    if (thunhaps != null)
        trans.AddRange(thunhaps);
    ViewBag.Difference = totalTN - totalCT;
    return PartialView("SearchResult", trans);
}
```

I very hard to try the change but I failed`

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "change this code from entity to linq"? Also is the above your starting code or your attempt so far?  Either way, please provide both so that we can better see what you are trying to do.

Comment: I might hav a quick answer for you: Should `if (search.MoTa != null) search.MoTa = "";` be `if (search.MoTa == null) search.MoTa = "";`? That apparent error may be allowing a null `search.MoTa` value to be passed into the `.Contains()` function. Recent C# versions also now support the long awaited `search.MoTa ??= "";` null-coalescing assignment syntax.

Answer (score 0):

When asking questions in StackOverflow you should be clearer.

A working sample would make a lot easier for anyone to help you.

That being said, you probably get the error because you are querying a recent created context object (and context.ThuNhaps is probably empty, and item.MoTa is null and item.Ngay is null, ...).

Now, I don't know if your question is about the error or "change the entity to linq", which I think you meant change the syntax of LINQ being used, from Query (Comprehension) Syntax to Lamda (Method) Syntax.

Something like:

```
thunhaps = context.ThuNhaps
  .Where(item => 
         item.UserID == userid
      && item.MoTa.Contains(search.MoTa)
      && item.Ngay.Value >= search.TuNgay 
      && item.Ngay <= search.DenNgay)
  .Select(item => 
    new Transaction
    {
      Id = item.Inc_Id,
      SoTien = (decimal)item.SoTien,
      MoTa = item.MoTa,
      GhiChu = item.GhiChu,
      NgayGD = item.Ngay.Value,
      TransType = "Income"
    });
```